# Nodejs Server Websocket limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, websocket, limits

I want to know if there is some type of limitation on the amount of open websockets a Node server can handle.

Right now I am testing a few hundred node instance client.js with the server, each opening its own websocket connection with the node server.
After around ~240 clients connected, I get the error: Connect Error: Error: read ECONNRESET

Is there any way to increase or remove these limitations? I am currently testing on one machine but want will move over to Amazon EC2 when testing thousands of websocket connections.

Comment: What operating system do you have ?

Comment: The latest OXS version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to increase the maximum amount of files you can have open.

Try running `ulimit -n 1024`.

Comment: Okay thank you! Am I to assume that raises the limit to 1024 ? also do I need to restart the bash shell?

Comment: one connection = one open file descriptor. Other system process can open file descriptor. Try use `lsof` to monitoring open file.

Comment: `ulimit -n` return current value